# Does $AB=AC$ $\forall A,B,C \in \mathbb{R}^{m,n}$ implies $B=C $?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've a very basic question on matrices.

I know that in general

$AB=AC \not\implies B=C $

But if $AB=AC$ is valid $\forall A,B,C \in \mathbb{R}^{m,n}$ does this imply that $B=C$?

Thanks in advice

Comment: As stated, this is never true.  In particular, you have to consider (or exclude) the case of $A = 0$.

Comment: This question makes no sense. $AB=AC$ does not hold for all $A,B,C$, so the premise if always false. Also, unless $m=n$, those matrix products are going to be ill-formed.

Answer (score 3):

Take $A$ to be an invertible matrix .

Comment: This fails to answer the question.  The question is: for which spaces $\Bbb R^{m,n}$ does the choice of (non-zero?) $A$ not matter?

Comment: there are not any choices available @Omnomnomnom